# Get tag value of azure resource in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

`(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroup).Tags` #shows o/p

Name Value

---

ENV    Dev

AppId  1

```
$Env = ((Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroup).Tags | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Env'}).Value
```

or

```
$Env1 = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroup).Tags | Where-Object { $.Name -eq 'Env'} | ForEach-Object { $.Value }
```

I am looking to find value Dev.
But above commands is not able to provide output , am I missing something?

Comment: You can try to run the command ```$result =(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name jimtest).Tags

$result['<your tag name>']```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jim said, you could use `$result['tagName']` to get the tag vaule.

```
$result=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "joeyRG").Tags
$result['tagName']
```

The output is as below:

[image]

Comment: FYI the AzureRm moodule  [is being replaced by Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.2.0).  Should run the command using the Az module [Get-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.2.0)